# "I was supposing..."? (past continuous possible?)

Tags: past-tense, continuous

I would like to know if it is possible to say "I was supposing..." or does it always have to be "I supposed..."? The example for what I am thinking of would be the following sentence:

> When we talked last Monday, I was supposing I would have a lot of free time this week to prepare the documents. However, I turned out to be quite busy.

or

> Last week I was supposing, I'd meet you in the office one of these days. I didn't know you went on holiday.

Are these possible?

Comment: Hi Ariane! Welcome to EL&L. They are *possible*, but we would normally use either "assuming" or "expecting", rather than "supposing".

Comment: What @OldBrixtonian said. Except that *in practice*, I bet on average far more people would actually say *When we talked last Monday **I thought** I would have a lot of free time...* It strikes me as something of an "affectation" to say ***...I was thinking...*** unless you have a good reason steering the conversational "focus" towards that point in past time (which is unlikely, since you're probably about to continue by saying something about what you think ***now***, not wittering on about why you thought differently in the past).

Answer (score 1):

"Supposed" is much better than "was supposing".

This might be better still:

> When we talked last Monday, I thought I would have a lot of free time
> this week to prepare the documents. However, I turned out to be quite
> busy.

You could say "was supposing", or "was thinking" if the thought was interrupted at the time:

> When we talked last Monday, I was thinking I would have a lot of free time
> this week to prepare the documents. Then I realized I would be quite
> busy.